# Test simulated html element width with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

### Use case

I want to detect if html tables get too wide, and if so, I want to flip the table header cells to become vertical (e.g. with `writing-mode: vertical-lr;`).

I want to update this on resize: If the viewport gets bigger, the text in the cells might become horizontal again.

The flip condition is whether the original table with horizontal labels would be wider than its container.

### Question

How do I determine the width a table *would have* with horizontal labels, without changing the table itself?

### Thoughts

My current idea would be to make an invisible copy of the table with horizontal labels, and use it as a "sensor". But I am afraid this will pollute the DOM and cause side effects somewhere. Also I would need to keep this copy updated all the time.

Is there a "best practice" or a known pattern to solve this problem?

Comment: You could determine the width with a mediaquery. When he is bigger then the given pixel/width make the table vertical. Something like this `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)`

Comment: @Minimumspace alright but this wouldn't be dynamic. I would have to know beforehand at which viewport width the cells need to become vertical, and for which table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually quite simple:

We *can* change the css on the table during the script run. Once we query a property like `element.width`, this will cause a reflow during the script execution, but it won't cause a repaint. So this means we can do the test without the need for a cloned DOM element, and without visible changes.

See https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/browser-reflow